# Javascript: Create an object with keys descending (numbers) order

Tags: javascript, for-loop, object-literal

I am trying to create an object that looks something like this:

```
{
    '2017': 2017,
    '2016': 2016,
    '2015': 2015,
    '2014': 2014
}
```

But for whatever reason, it keeps outputting me ascending order instead:

```
const EXAMPLE = () => {
    const exampleObj = {}

    for (let year = 2017; year >= 2014; year--) {
        exampleObj[year] = year
    }   


    return exampleObj
}

let example = EXAMPLE()
console.log(example)
```

Is it possible to achieve of what I desire in Javacript? I would choose `Map` but in my application, I need an object to render a certain component

Comment: order in objects is not guarantee: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order

Comment: Don't use an object if you need sorting.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does JavaScript Guarantee Object Property Order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order)

Comment: Actually, it's a dupe of [Sort JavaScript object by key](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5467129/215552). It's possible in ES6/ES2015.

Comment: yes actually I was looking for a link where they show how to use Map, but cannot find it btw: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map

Comment: "I need an object to render a certain component" what does this mean?

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible to achieve when you use an Object's keys. You should use a Map instead.

> 4.3.3 Object
>
> An object is a member of the type Object. It is an unordered
>   collection of properties each of which contains a primitive value,
>   object, or function. A function stored in a property of an object is
>   called a method.